# how to get length of the words typed in edittext on textview in android?

Tags: android, types, listener

How can I show the length of words typed into a textview?

This is the code, but my app stops responding if I type anything:

```
ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            t1.setText(ed1.getText().toString().length());
        }
    });
```

Code is written in onCreate().

Comment: you wan to show when you are typing ??? or after finishing typing

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @TanFang's answer , you need to cast the length to a string after getting it so the method will look like

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   t1.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
}
```

Another thing is you should initialise your TextView outside the `TextWatcher` interface calls since they are called each time the content of your `EditText` changes and initialising views during that is going to cause performance issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        TextView t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t1.setText(s.length());
    }
```